# loading auctex in xemacs

Tags: auctex, xemacs

I'm having problem with auctex in xemacs (I think). I get this error when I run load *.tex file in xemacs:

```
(1) (custom/warning) custom: widget custom-variable, option LaTeX-section-hook has no associated group
```

Here's the part of my init.el that's relevant:

```
(setq auto-mode-alist (append '(("\\.tex$"  . LaTeX-mode)) auto-mode-alist))
(require 'tex-site)
```

The error goes away if I comment the second line above.

Here's my M-x TeX-submit-bug-report:

```
Emacs  : XEmacs 21.5  (beta33) "horseradish" [Lucid] (i686-redhat-linux, Mule) of Tue Feb  5 2013 on buildvm-20.phx2.fedoraproject.org
Package: AUCTeX CVS-1.16 (-07--nil-nil)

current state:
==============
(setq
 window-system 'x
 LaTeX-version "2e"
 TeX-style-path '("style/" "auto/"
          "/usr/share/xemacs/xemacs-packages/etc/auctex/style/"
          "/usr/share/xemacs/xemacs-packages/etc/auctex/auto/")
 TeX-auto-save nil
 TeX-parse-self nil
 TeX-master t
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

I remove and reinstall auctex in xemacs and it now works. For the record the auctex that works with xemacs 21.5 is auctex 1.51.